# Get latest file with ant include (apache camel)

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to get file from SFTP with apache camel.

There is a format like:

**AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200902.txt**

So it contains **year month day  . txt**

But there can another file like:

**AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200910.txt**

So, there can be lots of files like:

```
**AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200902.txt**
**AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200903.txt**
**AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200904.txt**
```

I should get only latest one. It is according to modifed date or file name. They can both work.

I am using Spring boot + apache camel. My code is like this:

My expression is this:

```
"sftp://" +
                hostName +
                ":22" +
                mainPath +
                subPath +
                "?username=" + username +
                "&password=" + password +
                fileSecondPrefix +
                "&connectTimeout=10000" +
                "&soTimeout=40000" +
                "&timeout=40000" +
                "&stepwise=false" +
                "&maximumReconnectAttempts=4" +
                "&autoCreate=false" +//AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200706.txt
                "&strictHostKeyChecking=no" +
                "&preferredAuthentications=publickey,password" +
                "&disconnect=true" +
                "&stepwise=false" +
//                "&noop=true" +
//                "&fastExistsCheck=true" +
//                "&ignoreFileNotFoundOrPermissionError=false" +
//                "&throwExceptionOnConnectFailed=true" +
//                "&localWorkDirectory=" + "/temp" +
                "&consumer.bridgeErrorHandler=true"
                ;
```

and my route is:

```
from(GET_FILE_FROM_SFTP)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Getting the file from SFTP")
        .pollEnrich()
        .simple("${exchangeProperty.sftpExpression}")
        .timeout(5000L)
        .to(SAVE_RECEIVED_IDS)
        .end();

from(SAVE_RECEIVED_IDS)
        .log(LoggingLevel.INFO, DOCUMENT_RECONCILIATION_ROUTE, "Saving the received IDs")
        .process(saveReceivedsProcessor)
```

But it cant find file sometimes and throw exception for null input file in next root.

```
**"&sortBy=file:modified"**
```

So, it should get only last one

****AYLIK_BELGE_MUTABAKAT_20200904.txt****

How can make it work? This did:

```
&eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=false&maxMessagesPerPoll=1
```

take only one at time. But for example at local, when i run multiple times, it gets all of them one by one starting from the latest. What i want is get only last one every time. I can see from filezilla, modification date is not changed.

So, why is still getting other ones?

And other question is sometimes it cant find file. Because after 3 runs, 3 files are taken so it starts again?

I want it to reconnect but i cant see log for it or wait for timeout.

And it get always first file when i create two files.

Answer (score 0):

The FTP consumer is a polling consumer. It polls the source directory **at regular intervals**. Therefore, if you only consume 1 file, this is per polling request.

That means that on the first poll you get the newest file and after processing it is deleted or moved away. On the second poll it takes again the newest file (which was the second newest before) and so on.